# Differences between regex types

Tags: regex, syntax, find, posix

I'm reading the GNU `find`'s man page and stumbling upon this switch:

```
-regextype type
          Changes the regular  expression  syntax  understood  by  -regex  and
          -iregex  tests  which  occur  later on the command line.  Currently-
          implemented types are emacs (this is the default), posix-awk, posix-
          basic, posix-egrep and posix-extended.
```

What's the difference between those regex syntaxes? I'm more familiar with Ruby's regex, so what type of regex should I use with `find`?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

Comment: Hmm thanks, I found this URL: http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Regular-Expressions.html which pretty much answers my first question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regular expressions are implemented in many ways. POSIX Extended Expressions know the same metacharacters as POSIX Basic Expressions but with a few additions as you can see [on this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/syntax/posix_extended_regular_expression).

In some cases one might want to use a certain metacharacter known by one of those implementations and you can use this option to tell `find` which one you are using. 
If you only need a more basic expression, [posix-basic](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/syntax/posix_basic_regular_expression) would be enough.

Also you might just prefer the type of RegEx you are used to and `find` is able to interpret it correctly.

As fge mentioned, use [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) to learn more about the differences between RegEx syntactics.

Answer (score 1):

For a more general answer, because most of people arrive here by searching *"what are the different types of regex"*, here are some of the most common types of regex:

- **POSIX Basic Regular Expressions (BRE)**: This is a standard syntax used in UNIX-based systems for basic pattern matching. It uses a limited set of metacharacters, including ^, $, ., *, +, ?, [, ], (, ), and .
- **POSIX Extended Regular Expressions (ERE)**: This is a more powerful syntax used in UNIX-based systems for more advanced pattern matching. It adds more metacharacters, including {, }, |, and ^(.
- **Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE)**: This is a syntax used in
  many programming languages, including Perl, PHP, and Python. It adds
  many advanced features, such as lookaheads, lookbehinds, named
  capture groups, and more.
- **JavaScript Regular Expressions**: This is the syntax used by the
  JavaScript programming language. It is similar to PCRE but has some
  differences, such as the use of \b for word boundaries instead of \y.
- **.NET Regular Expressions**: This is the syntax used by the .NET Framework. It is similar to PCRE but has some differences, such as the use of (?) for named capture groups instead of (?P).

Each type of regex has its own set of rules and syntax, and some features may be available in one type but not in another. It's important to choose the right type of regex for your specific needs and to be aware of the differences between them when working with different systems or programming languages.

For the `find` command, note that the `-regex` option matches the entire path of a file, including its directory, so it may not be suitable for all search scenarios. If you only want to match the filename, you can use the `-name` option instead.