# Regex that should include brackets excludes them in Sublime Text

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have tested the following regex using two different online tools:

`\<(.*?)\>`

In both they produce the same result, which is to match `<any text within brackets>` including the brackets. This is what I want.

But in Sublime Text the result is different. It matches <`any text within brackets`> only. Brackets are excluded.

Here's some sample text I've been testing on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Text for testing regex -->
<data type="lorem">
<h3>Improving the lorem in your ipsum</h3>
</data>
<data type="image" number="1"/>
<data type="ipsum">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.
</data>
```

**Is this a bug with Sublime Text, or can the regex be modified to include the brackets in Sublime Text as well?**

Thanks.

Comment: Don't escape `<` and `>`.  They are _not_ regex metacharacters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This,

```
(<.*?>)
```

might simply work OK then.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EJjI9u/1/)

Curly brackets are metachars for capturing groups, which you just wanted to have your `<>` in them so that your capturing group $1 would become `(<.*?>)`, I guess.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zzcjqE/1). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/zzcjqE/1debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I can accept this answer in 12 minutes. In the meantime, if you know why this works, could you please add that to the answer?

Comment: There is no need at all here for a capture group.  Just use your original pattern with the `<` and `>` not escaped, i.e. use `<.*?>`

Answer (score 4):

In the regex type used by sublime the `<` and `>` characters are taken as literal if not escaped. So the regex you are looking for is `<(.*?)>`.

Escaping `<` has a special meaning which is "the start of a word". The same goes for a escaped `>` and the end of a word. This you can try in sublime with the regex `\<d` vs `d` and the example you provided.

Comment: I didn't know there were [different regex types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8639571/2454914). Today I learned...